# Can't drag-n-drop from sidebar to dropzone

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, uikit, interact.js

i want to achieve the following. I have an off-canvas left sidebar using [ui-kit](http://getuikit.com/docs/offcanvas.html) and for drag-n-drop i'm using [interact](http://interactjs.io/). I want to drag elements from sidebar to drop zone with id #inner-dropzone . What is preventing me to achieve this? I've tried removing z-index on left sidebar and also overflow-y: hidden. 
Is this related to css rules, or [restrictions](http://interactjs.io/docs/restriction/#restrict) on interact api?

```
restrict: {
  restriction: "inner-dropzone",
  endOnly: true,
  elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
},
```

Current implementation [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/arthurportas/pen/dPQeMy)

Answer (score 3):

The sidebar has `overflow-y: hidden` and `overflow-x` defaults to `auto`. Specifying `overflow: visible` instead would allow you to drag things out of sidebar.

If you'd prefer to avoid allowing visible overflow, then you would have to change the parent of the draggable element to one that brings it in front of the menu and set the position so that it doesn't appear to move when you change the parent.